# R Shiny Data Table is not showing fully as per width

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to display the data table is R shiny and passing the width argument in the syntax. But, the table is not displaying to the full width. So, I am trying to reduce the gap between table and input slider. Any help appreciated. Below is the syntax and image from the output.

```
#### Required Packages

Pckg_to_Inst = c("dashboardthemes", "shiny", "shinythemes",
                 "shinydashboard", "shinyWidgets", "DT", "bslib", "thematic", "shinydashboardPlus", "summaryBox")



##### Defining Negation 

'%not_in%' = Negate('%in%')

for(i in 1:length(Pckg_to_Inst)){
  
  if(Pckg_to_Inst[i] %not_in% installed.packages()) install.packages(Pckg_to_Inst[i],
                                                                     dependencies = TRUE)
  library(Pckg_to_Inst[i], character.only = TRUE)
}

#######################################################

ui <- fluidPage(
 
  titlePanel("Dashboard"),
  br(),
  navbarPage("",
             
             ###### Here : insert shinydashboard dependencies ######
             header = tagList(
               useShinydashboard()
             ),
             #######################################################
             
             navbarMenu("Data Tracker", icon = icon("database"),
                        
                        tabPanel("Test", fluid = TRUE,
 
                                 hr(),
                                 
                                 fluidRow(
                                   column(12,
                                          uiOutput("summarybox"))
                                 ),
                                 
                                 hr(),
                                 
                                 fluidRow(
                                   
                                   column(8, 
                                          column(width = 12,
                                                 mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("table1")))),
                                   
                                   
                                   column(4,
                                          box(
                                            width = 12,
                                            title = "Data Secription - ",
                                            selectInput(inputId = "Data_Type",
                                                        label = "Select Time Frame/Data Type",
                                                        choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                                                        selected = "A",
                                                        width = "220px"),
                                            background = "black",
                                            "A box with a solid black background"
                                          )))
                                 
                        ))

             
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
  
    DT::datatable(iris, class = 'cell-border stripe', 
                  options = list(
                    initComplete = JS(
                      "function(settings, json) {","$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'teal', 'color': 'black'});","}"),
                    scrollX = TRUE,  
                    scrollY = TRUE,
                    pageLength = 5),
                  extensions = 'Buttons',
                  selection = 'single',       ## enable selection of a single row
                  filter = 'top',              ## include column filters at the bottom
    )
    
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And attached is the output image. [image: R Shiny Output]

Answer (score 1):

Your `DT::dataTableOutput("table1")` is inside a `mainPanel` and by default, `mainPanel` has a width of 8 (the sidebar is taking the other 4).

from `?mainPanel`:

> Usage
> sidebarLayout(
> sidebarPanel,
> mainPanel,
> position = c("left", "right"),
> fluid = TRUE
> )
>
> sidebarPanel(..., width = 4)
>
> mainPanel(..., width = 8)

Comment: Ok. but in that case blank space should be not produced in between, right ?

Comment: The `width = 8` in `mainPanel` means "take up 8 out of 12 columns of the parent container". Or take up 2/3 of the parent container width. Removing the `mainPanel` and placing the data table in the column directly, should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing and removed the width as well as mainpanel. It solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can give a custom `height` and `width` to `dataTableOutput`.

```
library(shiny)  

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Dashboard"),
    br(),
    navbarPage("",
               
               ###### Here : insert shinydashboard dependencies ######
               header = tagList(
                 useShinydashboard()
               ),
               #######################################################
               
               navbarMenu("Data Tracker", icon = icon("database"),
                          
                          tabPanel("Test", fluid = TRUE,
                                   
                                   hr(),
                                   
                                   fluidRow(
                                     column(12,
                                            uiOutput("summarybox"))
                                   ),
                                   
                                   hr(),
                                   
                                   fluidRow(
                                     
                                     column(8, 
                                            column(width = 12,                                                    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("table1", width = '800px')))),
                                     
                                     
                                     column(4,
                                            box(
                                              width = 12,
                                              title = "Data Secription - ",
                                              selectInput(inputId = "Data_Type",
                                                          label = "Select Time Frame/Data Type",
                                                          choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                                                          selected = "A",
                                                          width = "220px"),
                                              background = "black",
                                              "A box with a solid black background"
                                            )))
                                   
                          ))
               
               
    ))
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      
      DT::datatable(iris, class = 'cell-border stripe', 
                    options = list(
                      initComplete = JS(
                        "function(settings, json) {","$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'teal', 'color': 'black'});","}"),
                      scrollX = TRUE,  
                      scrollY = TRUE,
                      pageLength = 5),
                    extensions = 'Buttons',
                    selection = 'single',       ## enable selection of a single row
                    filter = 'top',              ## include column filters at the bottom
      )
      
    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it is still showing the white space in between.

Comment: You can change the `width` in `DT::dataTableOutput("table1", width = '800px')` to anything of your choice. It works for me.

Comment: Actually, i have tried this solution before posting the question but not sure somehow it did not worked for me. But, removing mainPanel argument works for me. Thanks for your response.